# 404 error when i click privileges from chat

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar, achievements-dialog

The following URL gives a 404:

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/help/badges

what I did is just open the achievements tab from top bar then, I clicked that badges link. Privileges link also gives that same error.

[image]

Is it a normal behavior (I don't think 404 from a site's link is normal)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is a side-effect of the new top bar. Probably that new version of the achievements dropdown shouldn't be on chat.SO..

Comment: I'm sure this has come up before (but can't find it) and was supposedly fixed...

Comment: @JonClements Its still there...

Comment: For me it doesn't happen. I think it must be something I do with your device.

Comment: @JonClements - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291017/privileges-badges-links-in-achievements-dropdown-only-appear-in-chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The links should no longer be relative, which resolves the 404 issue. Syncing the header design across the network will further improve the behavior consistency here.

Comment: How it could be marked as status-completed.

Comment: @SankarRaj it was completed, *except* on chat.stackoverflow.com, because of the corner-case it is. We didn't see this on the first pass of logic changes. It was an unfortunate side-effect of view re-use and de-duplication a long time ago.

Comment: I think now its fixed. But still i can see the old top bar not the new one.

Comment: again it is showing 404 error